# Highcharts yAxis how to get more height when decimal point values on yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am graphing decimal data in highcharts,

1. the yAxis numbers are quite small but in a small range. Showing a picture, how can I solve this problem as second picture?
2. the xAxis numbers are not dynamic show space, if I put `xAxis: {tickInterval: 250}`, shows normal if yAxis use the regular number, but after I change yAxis to a decimal value, xAxis get very small too.

**Too narrow now**
[image: too narrow now]

**Ideal look like**
[image: ideal look like]

Comment: Please post a running example using jsfiddle

Comment: Hi @Allie, Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ogjLqaz0/ everything works as expected.